# 3 state checkbox required=true but checked and unchecked are valid. Intermediate should be invalid

Tags: html, jquery, checkbox

I have this 3 state checkbox:

```
<div>
    <input required type="checkbox" id="effectiveness" name="effectiveness">
</div>
```

and at the beginning the value is set to intermediate with jQuery like this:

```
$("#effectiveness").prop("indeterminate", true);
```

The required attribute checks if the attribute checked is true. But I want checked="true" and checked="false" to be valid. The only invalid state should be indeterminate.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you add full code which you trying.

Comment: The full code is in my next answer. It's not pure html. I'm working with the CMS Plone and the file is a .pt file which uses DTML (Document Template Markup Language). You can read more about this stuff in the zope documetation https://zope.readthedocs.io/en/latest/zopebook/AdvZPT.html#advanced-tal This is pretty new to me so the code might not be pretty but it works except the problem i described. I thougth it would be more easy to understand, if i only describe the relevant parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `indeterminate`, here's a brief note from CSS Tricks:

> The indeterminate state is visual only. The checkbox is still either
> checked or unchecked as a state. That means the visual indeterminate
> state masks the real value of the checkbox, so that better make sense
> in your UI! Like the checkboxes themselves, indeterminate state looks
> different in different browsers.

I don't think there's any browser supported validation for `indeterminate`. Since you're adding it yourself through jQuery, why not validate it as well?

Remove `required` attribute from your HTML and replace the code when `effectiveness` is `2` with:

```
$("#effectiveness").prop("indeterminate", true).prop("checked", false).attr("required", "true").on('change', function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('required');
});
```

Above code will effectively cause the browser to consider it `invalid`.

Answer (score 0):

Full code here:

```
<tr tal:define="effectiveness view/get_effectiveness">
    <td tal:condition="python: training['released']">
       <div>
          <input type="checkbox" id="effectiveness" name="effectiveness" ng-checked="effectiveness/effectiveness == 1" disabled="disabled" >
          <label for="effectiveness">Wirksamkeit</label>
        </div>
        <script tal:condition="python: effectiveness['effectiveness'] == 2">
            $("#effectiveness").prop("indeterminate", true);
        </script>
    </td>
    <td tal:condition="python: not training['released']">
        <div>
          <input required type="checkbox" id="effectiveness" name="effectiveness" ng-checked="effectiveness/effectiveness == 1" >
          <label for="effectiveness">Wirksamkeit</label>
        </div>
        <script tal:condition="python: effectiveness['effectiveness'] == 2">
            $("#effectiveness").prop("indeterminate", true);
        </script>
        <script tal:condition="python: effectiveness['effectiveness'] == 1">
            $("#effectiveness").prop("checked", true);
        </script>
        <script tal:condition="python: effectiveness['effectiveness'] == 0">
            $("#effectiveness").prop("checked", false);
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I still have the issue to make the unchecked state (not the indeterminate one) valid. I tried:

```
<script tal:condition="python: effectiveness['effectiveness'] == 0">
      $("#effectiveness").removeProp('required').prop("checked", false);
</script>
```

but this workes only if the value of the checkbox was already unchecked respectively effectiveness['effectiveness'] == 0, befor opening the page. When the state was checked (1) or indeterminate (2) and i'm switching the states by clicking in the checkbox, the unchecked state is invalid.